# Confusion regarding proof of tensor products preserve cokernels

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, modules, tensor-products, universal-property

[image]

[image]

I found this proof [here](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/MA3403H2018/MA3403_Lecture17.pdf) but I don't understand what they mean when they say that the existence of $C \to Q$ is implied by assumption? What assumption exactly? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is that $C$ is the cokernel of $A \to B.$ This way, any map $B \to Q$ such that $A \to B \to Q$ is zero uniquely factors through a map $C \to Q.$ Here this is applied to the "part" of $F$ which maps $B$ to $Q$.

Comment: Why does "any map $B \to Q$ such that $A \to B \to Q$ is zero" uniquely factor through $C \to Q$?

Comment: @S.D. By the definition (universal property) of the cokernel.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. Could you also explain why the existence of such a unique factorization implies that the sequence $A \otimes M \to B \otimes M \to C \otimes M \to 0$ is exact? The construction involving $Q$ seems a bit weird to me. I don't quite see how it's relevant to proving exactness.

Comment: I mean, what's the relevance of requiring $f \circ (i \otimes 1) = 0$ for starters?

Comment: @S.D. They prove that $C \otimes M$ also satisfies the universal property of the corresponding cokernel.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! And last question: Why are they able to replace $A \otimes M$, $B \otimes M$ and $C \otimes M$ by $A \times M$, $B \times M$ and $C \times M$ respectively in their commutative diagram? Why is it "equivalent"?

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389774/confusions-regarding-proof-of-tensor-products-preserve-right-exactness.

Comment: Do you know what the universal property of a tensor product is?

Comment: Yes, if there's an $R$-balanced map from $A \times M$ to some $\mathbb Z$-module $G$, then it factors through $A \otimes M$. But I'm not sure how that justifies replacing $A \otimes M$ by $A \times M$.

Comment: I don't know what a balanced map is. Maps from the tensor products correspond bijectively to bilinear maps from the products. This is the universal property and this is what is used here.

Comment: Uh, I haven't heard your version of the universal property anywhere. Could you point me to a reference? I'm just using Wikipedia's version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Definition.

Comment: Literally any reference which does not use this "balanced" term.