# Confusions regarding proof of tensor products preserve right exactness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, modules, tensor-products, universal-property

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388134/978567).

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

How are they able to replace $A \otimes M$, $B \otimes M$ and $C \otimes M$ by $A \times M$, $B \times M$ and $C \times M$ respectively in the commutative diagram?

I'm especially confused here since the tensor product doesn't just consist of simple tensors. It's possible that some weird linear combination $\sum_i a_i \otimes m_i$ lies in $\ker(j \otimes 1)$ but the individual simple tensors $a_i \otimes m_i$ don't, where each $a_i \in A, m_i \in M$.

Comment: The universal property of the tensor product says that a  homomorphism out of $A\otimes M$ is essentially the same thing as a bilinear function out of $A\times M$.

Comment: That's not the version of universal property I know. The one I've heard is that if there's a $R$-balanced homomorphism from $A \times M$ to $G$ (abelian group) then it factors through $A \otimes M$. I'm not sure how this is equivalent to what you're saying. Could you perhaps explain a bit?

Comment: I suspect that what you call an $R$-balanced homomorphism (terminology I haven't seen before) is what I call a bilinear function. If that's right and if you add to your universal property that the factorization is unique (which surely should be part of the property), then your version becomes a more detailed form of mine.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see. My confusion still is that since all elements of $A \otimes M$ don't have a pre-image in $A \times M$, I'm not sure it makes sense to say that $f$ and $F$ are essentially the same thing. Some weird elements like $\sum a_i \otimes m_i$ can be mapped to $0$ by $f$ but there's no pre-image of arbitrary $\sum a_i \otimes m_i$ in $A \times M$ that can be mapped to $0$ by $F$.

Comment: That's exactly why the universal property is important. It lets you define a homomorphism out of $A\otimes M$ by specifying what it should do to the elements of the form $a\otimes m$ without having to worry about all the other elements of $A\otimes M$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sure, but do all elements of $A \otimes M$ have a pre-image in $A \times M$? That's really my main confusion.

Comment: No, they do not. That's why I mentioned "all the other elements of $A\otimes M$" in my previous comment and why I emphasized that these other elements cause no difficulty, thanks to the universal property.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Well, but then when you're replacing $A \otimes M$ by $A \times M$ in the commutative diagram aren't you considering a commutative diagram involving strictly smaller modules? So I don't know how they're calling the two commutative diagrams "equivalent". Sure the second diagram implies the first but the opposite implication doesn't work I think.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh, actually I think I understand now. The homomorphism $f$ is entirely determined by its action on the elements of the form $a \otimes m$. Ooooh, makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: You should meditate on (1) the universal property of $\otimes$ and (2) the definitions of the homomorphisms in the given exact sequence.